# How to define a struct correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, struct

I have a struct where I define the size (width, height) of a square, and I don't know why the code doesn't work well. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
.h
  struct size{
        int width;
        int height;
   };

.m

   struct size a;
    a.width = 508;
    a.height = 686;
// I use it here.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I know that there's a class, the CGRect, but I don't know how to use it. It will work with it? And if the answer is yes, how I have to create it?

Comment: What do you mean with *"doesn't work well"*? What errors or problems are you experiencing?

Comment: I mean the typical syntax error in the Xcode :D

Comment: What error exactly. Please be more precise, give us more info to work with.

Comment: Don't describe the error.  Copy the error, edit your question, and paste in the error.  Also paste in the code that causes the error, and a few surrounding lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use Apple provided types, you have:

- `CGSize` for sizes (with `width` and `height`)
- `CGPoint` for locations (with `x` and `y`)
- and `CGRect`, which combines the two.

Example usage:

```
CGPoint p;
CGSize s;
CGRect r;

p.x = 1;
p.y = 2;
// or:
p = CGPointMake(1, 2);

s.width = 3;
s.height = 4;
// or:
s = CGSizeMake(3, 4);

r.origin.x = 1;
r.origin.y = 2;
r.size.width = 3;
r.size.height = 4;
// or:
r.origin = p;
r.size = s;
// or:
r = CGRectMake(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: @user1176834 - then you should accept the answer and/or vote it up.